# Can't connect to mongodb running on EC2, Ubuntu 16

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

This is my mongo.conf

```
storage:
    dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
    journal:
        enabled: true

systemLog:
    destination: file
    logAppend: true
    path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
    authorization: enabled
```

And I'm starting it via systemctl which does this:

```
/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Created an admin user like so:

```
mongo
> use admin
> db.createUser({ user:"user001", pwd:"pwd001", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]})
```

I can access mongo on EC2 via:

```
mongo -u user001 -p pwd001 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

However, when I try to access it on my local via:

```
mongo -u user001 -p pwd001 --authenticationDatabase admin --host 58.17.53.6
```

I get this error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: 58.17.53.6:27017/test
2017-10-30T19:42:33.302-0700 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 58.17.53.6:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2017-10-30T19:42:33.304-0700 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 58.17.53.6:27017 (58.17.53.6), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

Also, my security group for instance looks like this:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `27017 != 27107`

Comment: OMG! You're my hero! hahaha